# Bare-metal Arduino C Code won't blink LED

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, avr, bare-metal

I am trying to learn embedded C on Arduino the bare-metal, no IDE way...and I was trying out writing some of the `avr/io.h` macros myself in a different manner. I tried Blink LED by using direct memory addresses (which works) and by pointer for struct with bit-fields (*which doesn't work*).

The F_CPU macro is defined.
Device: Arduino UNO R3 board, which has ATMEGA328P chip.

Direct Memory Addresses (works as intended):

```c
#include <util/delay.h>

int main (void) {

    *(volatile unsigned char*) 0x24 |= 1 << 5;

    while(1) {

        *(volatile unsigned char*) 0x25 |= 1 << 5;

        _delay_ms(500);

        *(volatile unsigned char*) 0x25 &= ~(1 << 5);

        _delay_ms(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assembly by compiler:

```
    .file   "main.c"
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
    .text
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
/* prologue: function */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    sbi 0x4,5
.L2:
    sbi 0x5,5
    ldi r18,lo8(1599999)
    ldi r24,hi8(1599999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(1599999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    cbi 0x5,5
    ldi r18,lo8(1599999)
    ldi r24,hi8(1599999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(1599999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    rjmp .L2
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Fedora 13.2.0-1.fc38) 13.2.0"
```

Struct with bit-fields way (doesn't work, LED is just turned ON):

```c
#include <util/delay.h>

typedef unsigned char   byte;

volatile struct {
    volatile byte PINB0: 1;
    volatile byte PINB1: 1;
    volatile byte PINB2: 1;
    volatile byte PINB3: 1;
    volatile byte PINB4: 1;
    volatile byte PINB5: 1;
    volatile byte PINB6: 1;
    volatile byte PINB7: 1;
} *__ATMEGA_328P_PINB = (void*) 0x23;

volatile struct {
    volatile byte DDB0: 1;
    volatile byte DDB1: 1;
    volatile byte DDB2: 1;
    volatile byte DDB3: 1;
    volatile byte DDB4: 1;
    volatile byte DDB5: 1;
    volatile byte DDB6: 1;
    volatile byte DDB7: 1;
} *__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB = (void*) 0x24;

volatile struct {
    volatile byte PORTB0: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB1: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB2: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB3: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB4: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB5: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB6: 1;
    volatile byte PORTB7: 1;
} *__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB = (void*) 0x25;

int main (void) {

    __ATMEGA_328P_DDRB->DDB5 = 1;

    while(1) {
        __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB->PORTB5 = 1;

        _delay_ms(500);

        __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB->PORTB5 = 0;

        _delay_ms(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assembly by compiler:

```
    .file   "main.c"
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
    .text
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
/* prologue: function */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    lds r30,__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB
    lds r31,__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB+1
    ld r24,Z
    ori r24,lo8(1<<5)
    st Z,r24
.L2:
    lds r30,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB
    lds r31,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB+1
    ld r24,Z
    ori r24,lo8(1<<5)
    st Z,r24
    ldi r18,lo8(1599999)
    ldi r24,hi8(1599999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(1599999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    lds r30,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB
    lds r31,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB+1
    ld r24,Z
    andi r24,lo8(~(1<<5))
    st Z,r24
    ldi r18,lo8(1599999)
    ldi r24,hi8(1599999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(1599999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    rjmp .L2
    .size   main, .-main
.global __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB
    .data
    .type   __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB, @object
    .size   __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB, 2
__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB:
    .word   37
.global __ATMEGA_328P_DDRB
    .type   __ATMEGA_328P_DDRB, @object
    .size   __ATMEGA_328P_DDRB, 2
__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB:
    .word   36
.global __ATMEGA_328P_PINB
    .type   __ATMEGA_328P_PINB, @object
    .size   __ATMEGA_328P_PINB, 2
__ATMEGA_328P_PINB:
    .word   35
    .ident  "GCC: (Fedora 13.2.0-1.fc38) 13.2.0"
.global __do_copy_data
```

My Makefile:

```
PROGRAM := main
PORT := 8080
MEMORY := 512M

ARDUINO_DEV := /dev/ttyACM0

# Toolchains
TOOLCHAIN := avr

CC := $(TOOLCHAIN)-gcc
LD := $(TOOLCHAIN)-ld
OBJCPY := $(TOOLCHAIN)-objcopy
FLASH := avrdude

# File Names
C_DIR := src
C_FILES := $(wildcard ./$(C_DIR)/*.c)

OUTPUT_DIR := build
OUTPUT_FILES := $(patsubst ./$(C_DIR)/%.c, ./$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.c.o, $(C_FILES))

# Flags
# https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html
C_FLAGS := -mmcu=atmega328p \
    -Wall \
    -O2 \
    -save-temps \
    -c \
    -DF_CPU=16000000UL

FLASH_FLAGS := -p m328p \
    -c arduino \
    -e \
    -P $(ARDUINO_DEV)

all: $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).hex

clean:
    @rm -f build/**
    @printf "[CLEANED UP]\n"

./$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.c.o: ./$(C_DIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<
    @printf "[COMPILED]\t$@!\n"

./$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.s.o: ./$(ASM_DIR)/%.s
    @$(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<
    @printf "[COMPILED]\t$@!\n"

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).elf: $(OUTPUT_FILES)
    @$(LD) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).elf $(OUTPUT_FILES) -Map=$(OUTPUT_DIR)/linker.map
    @printf "[LINKED]\t$@!\n"

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).hex: $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).elf
    @$(OBJCPY) -O ihex $(OUTPUT_DIR)//$(PROGRAM).elf $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).hex
    @printf "[CREATE BIN]\t$@!\n"

flash: $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).hex
    @sudo $(FLASH) $(FLASH_FLAGS) -U flash:w:$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PROGRAM).hex
    @printf "[FLASHED]\t$<!\n"

.PHONY: all clean flash
```

My dir structure:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── linker.map
│   ├── main.c.i
│   ├── main.c.o
│   ├── main.c.s
│   ├── main.elf
│   └── main.hex
├── compile_commands.json
├── Makefile
└── src
    └── main.c

3 directories, 9 files
```

Edit: Added the full assembly (it's the assembly generated by the compiler due to `-save-temps`, not a disassembly by `objdump`), and my Makefile

Comment: I don't have experience with the Arduino, but the assembly output is clear that the first example recognizes that addresses 0x24 and 0x25 are locations that are directly bit addressable, and generates bit set and bit clear instructions.  In the second example, that is clearly not the case.  You may want to see if the compiler you are using has a way to make it clear that __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB and __ATMEGA_328P_DDRB are directly bit addressable.

Comment: I feel it does recognize setting 1 and 0 to being bit operations....it gives `ori r24,lo8(1<<5)` and `andi r24,lo8(~(1<<5))` for  5th bit (field), and I _think_ stores it back using `st Z,r24`.

Comment: Again, I am not familiar with this particular processor, but normally Z refers to the processor's Z (zero) flag.  In the first example, the compiler generates "cbi 0x05, 5" to clear the LED, and "sbi 0x05, 5" to set the LED.  In the first example, the compiler somehow recognizes that byte address 0x25 can be bit addressed with the cbi and sbi instructions at bit addressable location 5.  That is not the case in the second example.  I wish I could be of more help than that.

Comment: @SteveMathwig Actually, `Z` refers to the register pair R30/R31, as `X` and `Y` do for R26/R27 and R28/R29, respectively.

Comment: How is the LED connected to the port pin? Is there a current limiting resistor?

Comment: Compile the code using the regular, working register definitions from `avr/io.h` and make sure it works.  Then look at the assembly generated by that code and make sure it's the same as your code.  If it's not, then make your code closer and closer to the code in io.h until it works.  The [Compile explorer](https://godbolt.org) could be useful.

Comment: How do you compile and link your program? Please provide full disassembly. I suspect `.data` section is not loaded into RAM.

Comment: Is it not because you’re using addresses 0x24 and 0x25 in the hard coded example but your bit field example uses pointers to addresses 0x23 and 0x24?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Second version (with bit field structures) compiled and flashed to Arduino Mini Pro blinks the LED properly. I bet on invalid compilation flags on your side.

Comment: That is not Arduino code.  It may be an Arduino board, but Arduino is a series of hardware designs and a software framework.  This is just plain C code for an AVR MCU (in amn Arduino board perhaps).

Comment: @dimich I've added the Makefile I used.

Comment: @thebusybee It's the onboard LED of an Arduino UNO R3 board. Port B5. I do assume it has got a resistor with it.

Comment: @resyfer Your ELF file is linked without C runtime, so data section is not copied from flash into SRAM at startup. See  my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305805/makefile-failing-to-flash-code-to-atmega328p/77306149#77306149). Add `-mmcu=atmega328p` to linker flags.

Comment: @dimich Yes, it worked, I've accepted the "redirect" option given by SO....that you very much. It was very puzzling indeed.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you've cast the pointer to a void* and it's treating it as a 16 bit pointer instead of a 8 bit.

```
lds r30,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB
lds r31,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB+1
```

Take a look at whats written in the data table for __ATMEGA_328P_PORTB I assume it will look like

```
__ATMEGA_328P_PINB:
    .word   35
__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB:
    .word   36
__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB:
    .word   37
```

So it would actually Load in 0x2425 into the Z register instead of 0x24 as expected

Comment: `lds` is "Load direct from SRAM". `lds r30,__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB` loads byte from address `__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB` into low part of register Z (which should contain 0x25), next instuction loads byte into high part of register Z from address `__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB+1` (which should contain 0x00). So Z contains `0x0025`. `ld r24,Z` loads value from address in Z, i.e. 0x0025 which is correct PORTB register address.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be that whatever compiler you are using doesn't understand that you are trying to load an address into a register pair, it tries to do:

```
lds r30,__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB
lds r31,__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB+1
```

What actually happens here is equivalent to:

```
r30 = content of address 0x24 (state of DDRB)
r31 = content of address 0x25 (state of PORTB)
```

or in more C style syntax:

```
r30 = *(char*)0x24
r31 = *((char*)0x24+1)
```

Which means that the pointer register `Z` which is also called `r30:r31` points at address `0x2524`, instead of at address `0x0024` which is the address of the `DDRB` register.

If you want to access the register via a pointer, you would want the generated assembly to be:

```
ldi r30, low(__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB)
ldi r31, high(__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB)
```

So to achieve that, you would use something equivalent to your first example:

```
int main (void) {

    *__ATMEGA_328P_DDRB |= (1 << DDB5);

    while(1) {
        *__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB |= (1 << PB5);

        _delay_ms(500);

        *__ATMEGA_328P_PORTB &= ~(1 << PB5)

        _delay_ms(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand your wish to use bitsets for nicer syntax, but it wont be done without some nasty preprocessor macros and going into writing pure assembly.

Comment: OP's second example works fine when compiled with avr-gcc. Their implementation is correct.